# problems with switch statement involving functions

Tags: c++, function, switch-statement

This program is not prompting me for input. I need help with defining, and calling functions properly. menu() is supposed to display a string of text, and ask the user to select a number 1-4, and if the user enters a number outside of that it will ask the user to enter an appropriate number until 1-4 is entered. The value of menu() will be stored in a variable 'choice' and be used in a switch statement. 
Inside of the switch statement the corresponding choice functions[getSum(), getFactor(), getExpo(), and exit()] are called. They each need to ask the user for an integer, and perform some arithmetic, and return some output text to the user with the calculated value. 
All of this is inside of a do while loop repeating this process, until the user chooses the option 4 to quit the program, where the exit() function will return a string exit message to the user and then the program will terminate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int menu();
long int getSum();
long int getFactor();
long int getExpo();
string exit();


int main()
{
        const int SUM = 1, // Summation choice
    FACTOR = 2, // Factorial choice
    EXPO = 3, // Exponential choice
    QUIT = 4; // Exit choice


    int choice; // Numerical menu choice
    long int sums, facts, expos;
    string quits;


    // Force the console to print standard notation
    cout << fixed << setprecision(0);

    // Do-While loop controlled by the users choices
    do
    {
        choice = menu();



        switch (choice) // Start switch option
        {
            case SUM: // 1st choice
            sums = getSum();
            break;

        case FACTOR: // 2nd choice
            facts = getFactor();
            break;

        case EXPO: // 3rd choice
            expos = getExpo();
            break;

        case QUIT: // 4th choice
            quits = exit();
            break;

        default: // Default choice
            // Error message for input outside domain
            cout << "Please make a selection of either 1,2,3 or 4.\n\n";
            cin >> choice; // Repeat attempt to gather input from user
        }
    }
    while (menu() != QUIT);

    return 0;
}

int menu()
{
    int choice;
    cout << "\n\t\tMathematical Menu\n" // Header
    << "1) Summation\n" // 1st choice
    << "2) Factorial\n" // 2nd choice
    << "3) Exponential\n" // 3rd choice
    << "4) Exit Program\n\n" // 4th choice
    << "Please make a selection\n" // Ask user for imput choice
    << "of either 1,2,3 or 4.\n\n";
    cin >> choice; // Gather input from user
    return choice;
}

long int getSum()
{
    int total = 0, userNum, counter;

    // Ouput statement to user
    cout << "Please enter a positive integer value greater than 0 \n"
    << "and less than 10,000,000.\n\n";
    cin >> userNum; // Repeat attempt to gather input from user

    // Compare input to domain
    if (userNum < 0 || userNum > 10000000)
    {
        // Error message for input outside domain
        cout << "Please check your entry and try again.\n\n";
    cin >> userNum; // Repeat attempt to gather input from user
}

// Perform arithmetic summation
for (counter = 1; counter <= userNum; counter++)
{
    total += counter; // Running count
}
cout << "The total value for the added numbers 1 to \n"
<< userNum << " is:\n"<<total;
return total;
}

long int getFactor()
{
int total, userNum, counter;

total = 1;
// Output statement to user
cout << "Please enter a positive integer from 0 \n"
<< "and less than 100.\n\n";
cin >> userNum; // Gather input from user

// Compare input to domain
if (userNum > 100 || userNum < 0)
{
    // Error message if input is outside domain
    cout << "Please check your entry and try again.\n\n";
    cin >> userNum; // Repeat attempt to gather input from user
}

// Perform arithmetic factorial
for (counter = 1; counter <= userNum; counter++)
{
    total *= counter; // Running count
}

// Display arithmetic output to user
cout << "The total value for the multiplied numbers 1 to \n"
<< userNum << " is:\n";
return total;
}

long int getExpo()
{
int total, userNum, counter;

total = 0;
// Output statement to user
cout << "Please enter a positive integer from 0 \n"
<< "and less than 100.\n\n";
cin >> userNum; // Gather input from user

// Compare input to domain
if (userNum > 100 || userNum < 0)
{
    // Error message if input is outside domain
    cout << "Please check your entry and try again.\n\n";
    cin >> userNum; // Repeat attempt to gather input from user
}

// Perform arithmetic exponential
for (counter = 1; counter <= userNum; counter++)
{
    total = pow(2.0, userNum); // Running count
}

// Display arithmetic output to user
cout << "The total value for the exponential function is \n";
return total;
}

string exit()
{
// Exit message
return "Don't be gone for too long...\n";

}`
```

Comment: You're going to need to explain your problem a lot better. Are you asking someone to explain to you what your code is doing? Are you getting incorrect results?

Comment: a) What is the question? b) The code sample is way too long, provide the shortest possible code which matches your question. c) This is no site to solve your homework.

Comment: `getSum` seems to have a couple of lines missing ?

Comment: @Flovdis I am not asking anyone to solve my 'homework' clearly I have tried to solve this on my own, and have attempted to clear up any compiler errors. I simply don't understand how to appropriately call and pass values with the functions I've defined.

Comment: @suspectus It's just buggy, easily seen - see my answer and the comment. I think that there is enough struggle to warrant help.

Comment: @Johann Blais It's just buggy, easily seen - see my answer and the comment. I think that there is enough struggle to warrant help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not call `menu()` more than once: it will prompt the user twice.

Do not return anything from a function that does all the work anyway. Make it

```
void getExpo(){ ...; return; }
```

Call:

```
getExpo();
```

Comment: I don't believe I'm calling menu() more than once. I have a prototype, a call, and then a definition. Thanks for the attempt, however I tried to fix with your suggestion and still get 0 prompts to input data, etc.

Comment: You have `do { choice = menu();...` and `...} while( menu() != QUIT)`, and 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: Just tried the program: apart from prompting twice (after the first selection, where it prompts only once) there are some other errors. For '1', a 32-bit int isn't sufficient, given the upper bound for the user input. For '2', the result is not displayed, and using 100 as an upper bound isn't going to produce meaningful results with any integer mode. I didn't check '3'.

Comment: Thank you @luane, I was having issues with my IDE the entire time. I thought all the code I wrote wasn't even working at all. I created a new project, and took the tips from your answer and I'm good to go. Thank you again.